# jquery dynamically create html table and bind sharepoint list items in it

Tags: sharepoint

I have scenario where i need to bind sharepoint list to the dynamically cretaed html table and use the jquery in content editor webpart to show the table in site.Please help me with this regards.I am using sharepoint 2010.Thanks in advance.

I was trying something here but no luck please help me around with this.Thanks`enter code here`

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    var _clientContext;
    var _web;
    alert("Working")
    //ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(RetrieveListItems, "sp.js");


    function RetrieveListItems() {
        alert("Test");
        _clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        alert(Context);
        _web = _clientContext.get_web();
        alert(web);
        var list = _web.get_lists().getByTitle('Planning Partners');
        alert(list);
       // var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
        var myquery = new SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery();
        allItems = list.getItems(myquery);
        _clientContext.load(allItems);
        _clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.success), Function.createDelegate(this, this.failed));
    }

    function success() {
        var Image = null;
        var Linkurl = null;
        var Title = null;
        //        var sHtml = "";
        alert("success");
        var ListEnumerator = this.allItems.getEnumerator();

        while (ListEnumerator.moveNext()) {

            var currentItem = ListEnumerator.get_current();

            Image = currentItem.get_item('Image');
            Linkurl = currentItem.get_item('Linkurl');
            Title = currentItem.get_item('Title');
            //var tbl = document.createElement("tbl");
            var row = document.createElement("tr");
            var $table = $('<table>');
            $table.append('<caption>MyTable</caption>')
            $table.append('<thead>');
            $table.append('<tr>');

            if (Image != oListItem.get_item('Image')) {
                var cell = document.createElement("td");
                var cellText = document.createElement("<image imgurl='" + oListItem.get_item('Image') + "'></Image>");
                cell.appendChild(cellText);
                row.appendChild(cell);
            }


            if (Linkurl != oListItem.get_item('Linkurl')) {
                var cell = document.createElement("td");
                var cellText = document.createElement("<a target='_blank'  href ='" + oListItem.get_item('Linkurl') + "'>" + oListItem.get_item('Title') + "</a>");
                cell.appendChild(cellText);
                row.appendChild(cell);
            }

            if (Title != oListItem.get_item('Title')) {
                var cell = document.createElement("td");
                var cellText = document.createElement("<p>" + Title + "</p>");
                cell.appendChild(cellText);
                row.appendChild(cell);
            }
            $table.append('</tr>');
            $table.append('</thead>');
            tblBody.appendChild(row);
            tbl.appendChild(tblBody);
            body.appendchild(tbl);
        }
    }


    //            sHtml += '<table><tr><td><img src="' + Image + '" height="55px" width="55px"></td><td><table><tr><td valign="top"><div class="fieldsTitle">' + Linkurl + '</div></td></tr><tr><td valign="top">' + Title + '<a href="/">Read More >></a></td></tr><tr><td></td></tr></table></td></tr></table>';

    //        document.getElementById('MainDiv').innerHTML = sHtml;
    //    }

    function failed(sender, args) {
        alert("failed Message" + args.gte_message());
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating elements through JavaScript, simply create a variable to store theHTML tags and finally add on page using Jquery. Use below script, hope this will help you.
If "Image" and "Linkurl" are HyperLink or Picture Column then use currentItem.get_item('Image').**get_url()** . I think this was the issue in your case :)

```
            <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js "></script>

            <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
                var _clientContext;
                var _web;
                ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(RetrieveListItems, "sp.js");
                function RetrieveListItems() {
                    _clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
                    _web = _clientContext.get_web();
                    var list = _web.get_lists().getByTitle('Planning Partners');
                    var myquery = new SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery();
                    allItems = list.getItems(myquery);
                    _clientContext.load(allItems);
                    _clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.success), Function.createDelegate(this, this.failed));
                }

                function success() {
                    var Image = null;
                    var Linkurl = null;
                    var Title = null;
                    var txtHTML = "";
                    var ListEnumerator = this.allItems.getEnumerator();
                    while (ListEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                        var currentItem = ListEnumerator.get_current();
                        Image = currentItem.get_item('Image');
                        Linkurl = currentItem.get_item('Linkurl');
                        Title = currentItem.get_item('Title');
                        var row = document.createElement("tr");

                        txtHTML = txtHTML + "<tr>";
                        txtHTML = txtHTML + "<td>";
                        if (Image != null) {
                            txtHTML = txtHTML + "<image src='" + Image.get_url() + "'></Image>";
                        }
                        txtHTML = txtHTML + "</td>";

                        txtHTML = txtHTML + "<td>";
                        if (Linkurl != null) {
                            txtHTML = txtHTML + "<a target='_blank'  href ='" + Linkurl.get_url() + "'>" + Title + "</a>";
                        }
                        txtHTML = txtHTML + "</td>";

                        txtHTML = txtHTML + "<td>";
                        if (Title != null) {
                            txtHTML = txtHTML + "<p>" + Title + "</p>";
                        }
                        txtHTML = txtHTML + "</td>";
                        txtHTML = txtHTML + "</tr>";
                    }
                    $("#tblCustomListData").append(txtHTML);
                }
                function failed(sender, args) {
                    alert("failed Message" + args.gte_message());
                }
            </script>
            <table id="tblCustomListData" border="1">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Image
                        </th>
                        <th>Linkurl
                        </th>
                        <th>Title
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
```

Comment: Rather than
txtHTML = txtHTML + "</td>";
use
txtHTML += "</td>";